# View changes gitlab in visual studio code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, gitlab

I am using visual studio code to develop my flutter app.
I need to share it with a colleague. I was able to make the transfer on gitlab very easily.
I have a problem.
When my colleague makes changes to my code, before "taking" his changes I would like to be able to view them on visual studio code.
I have tried several avenues, but each time my code is synchronized and modified according to the changes made
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1:Click Git icon on left side of VS Code*

---

*2:If you've made changes to the file(s) since last commit, you'll see the file(s) listed under "CHANGES"*

---

*3:Right click the file name (under "CHANGES") and click "Open Changes"*

---

*4:This will open the two versions of the file side by side with the changes highlighted*

[image]

I believe this is how you see the changes that your college made on GitLab